# Accessibility and the title tag for images

Tags: html, image, accessibility, alt

I understand that for a website to be "accessible", images should in general have the alt tag. The alt tag should provide alternate text for the image, in particular when the image contains content that is relevant for the user.

When one uses the `alt` tag like :`<img alt= "alttext" ...>` the alttext does not display when the mouse hovers over the image. If one adds the `title` tag, then one can have the alttext displayed.

My question is: **Is the use of the `title` tag appropriate for this?**

I have found a bit of conflicting information on this:

- [This site](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/01/html5-accessibility-chops-title-attribute-use-and-abuse/) seems to discourage the use.
- [This site](http://accessibility.psu.edu/images/imageshtml/) seems to say that the use is fine.

Answer (score 2):

`alt` attribute is displayed when the image cannot be loaded, and used for accesibility when that feature is set in the browser. It also helps for Search Engine Positioning (SEO) (thanks @Chris for noting this)

[alt HTML reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/img.html#img.attrs.alt)

`title` is just *Advisory information* and it's disadvantaged for accesibility purposes. Source: [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/global-attributes.html#the-title-attribute)

[title HTML reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.title)

---

For example, [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/image-alt-text-viewer/hinbolcnfifkhlcehoakdledkfjiaeeg) is an extension for chrome (offered by google) that show `alt` text, not `title`..

Comment: My understanding is that `alt` has all the same SEO benefits that you describe for `title`.

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to have some text appear when you hover over an image, then yes, the title attribute is appropriate. Ensure that any key information in the title text is duplicated elsewhere on the page.

If your aim is to provide additional information about the image to all your readers, then you will need to consider an alternative way for keyboard and touch based users to read that content. It may be simpler just to display the content next to the image for all users.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your image is focusable, relying on a tooltip is not a solution.

Having to use the mouse to discover the subject of an image is not accessible to keyboard only users.

What you need to do is :

- providing an alt text for screenreader users (people who can't see it)
- provide contextual description next to the image if you need to give all of your visitors more elements (like copyright owner, artwork title, ...).

Note that you have to set an alt text, it still can be empty if the alternative is not relevant (decorative images, or redundant information).